# Turning this switch-statement into a function (and separate logic from content)?

Tags: php, switch-statement

Basically, I would like to turn the following switch-statement (which is in a Wordpress template file):

```
    <?php preg_match( '!<div class="thumblock ">(.*)</div>!si' , wp_gdsr_render_article_thumbs(0, false, "", 0, "", false) , $n );
    $thumbs_number = strip_tags( $n[1] ); ?>

    <div class="topic-like-count
        <?php // Apply style based on number of votes
            switch ($thumbs_number) {
                case ($thumbs_number == 0):
                case ($thumbs_number == 1): echo ' average'; break;
                case ($thumbs_number == 2):
                case ($thumbs_number == 3): echo ' good'; break;
                case ($thumbs_number == 4):
                case ($thumbs_number == 5): echo ' great'; break;
                case ($thumbs_number == 6):
                case ($thumbs_number == 7): echo ' excellent'; break;
                default:
                    if ($thumbs_number <= -1) echo "bad";
                    else if ($thumbs_number > 7) echo "brillant";
            }
        ?>
      ">
        <h4><?php wp_gdsr_render_article_thumbs(); ?></h4>

        <?php if ( $thumbs_number == 1 || $thumbs_number == -1 ) : ?>
            <span><?php _e( 'vote' ); ?></span>
        <?php else : ?>
            <span><?php _e( 'votes' ); ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

into a function (stored in **functions.php**) that I can use like this in a template:

`<?php rating_class(); ?>`

Any suggestions?

(The question has a bit of Worpdress but I think it is more a php question)

Comment: use `global $thumbs_number;` and the same `switch`...

Comment: You should sent $thumbs_number as a parameter. Avoid global.

Comment: @Wesley van Opdorp, i just said what can be done to call a function as OP posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the rating class:

```
function get_rating_class($thumbs_number) {
    if ($thumbs_number < 0) return 'bad';
    if ($thumbs_number < 2) return 'average';
    if ($thumbs_number < 4) return 'good';
    if ($thumbs_number < 6) return 'great';
    if ($thumbs_number < 8) return 'excellent';
    return 'brillant';
}
```

Print the rating class:

```
function rating_class($thumbs_number) {
    echo get_rating_class($thumbs_number);
}
```

Print the vote phrase:

```
function votes($thumbs_number) {
    echo ($thumbs_number == 1 || $thumbs_number == -1) ? _e('vote') : _e('votes');
}
```

Template code:

```
<?php
    preg_match( '!<div class="thumblock ">(.*)</div>!si' , wp_gdsr_render_article_thumbs(0, false, "", 0, "", false) , $n );
    $thumbs_number = strip_tags( $n[1] );
?>

<div class="topic-like-count <?php rating_class($thumbs_number); ?>">
    <h4><?php wp_gdsr_render_article_thumbs(); ?></h4>
    <span><?php votes($thumbs_number); ?></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow thanks. By the way, why did you use an if-statement instead of the switch-statement?

Comment: For the simple reason that it is more readable and requires less code.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php // Apply style based on number of votes
    function rating_class($thumbs_number)
    {
        switch ($thumbs_number) {
            case ($thumbs_number == 0):
            case ($thumbs_number == 1): echo ' average'; break;
            case ($thumbs_number == 2):
            case ($thumbs_number == 3): echo ' good'; break;
            case ($thumbs_number == 4):
            case ($thumbs_number == 5): echo ' great'; break;
            case ($thumbs_number == 6):
            case ($thumbs_number == 7): echo ' excellent'; break;
            default:
                if ($thumbs_number <= -1) echo "bad";
                else if ($thumbs_number > 7) echo "brillant";
        }
    }
?>
```

`<?php rating_class($thumbs_number); ?>`

Comment: is `<?php rating_class(1); ?>` returning `case ($thumbs_number == 1): echo ' average'; break;`? Because the value of `$thumbs_number` is determined by `<?php preg_match( '!<div class="thumblock ">(.*)</div>!si' , wp_gdsr_render_article_thumbs(0, false, "", 0, "", false) , $n );
    $thumbs_number = strip_tags( $n[1] ); ?>` dynamically. Not by me.

Comment: Yes, the 1 was just an example. For it to be dynamic you can use $thumbs_number instead of 1, as per my updated post.